# Installation of avast fails

Tags: installation

I try to install avast on my Ubuntu. Therefore, I installed one of the .deb packages from http://files.avast.com/lin/repo/pool/ after some registration. 
Then I open the package using the Ubuntu Software Center which says that scan & avast can be used from terminal.

But when I type `$ scan <path-to-test-file>/test.txt` then I get the following error message:

```
connect(): /var/run/avast/scan.sock: No such file or directory
```

So,during the installation, it does not create `scan.sock` . The /`var/run/avast/` is completely empty.

After registration, I get an email with the following steps to do:

```
1. Add the Avast repository to the system repositories
# echo "deb http://deb.avast.com/lin/repo debian release" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt key add /path/to/avast.gpg
# apt-get update

2. Install the Avast package and optionally the "avast-fss" and avast-proxy packages.
# apt-get install avast
# apt-get install avast-fss
# apt-get install avast-proxy
```

I did every step, but again, `scan.sock` is not there.

Can someone help ?

Comment: Did you solved it? As I understand avast service has to be running, but it fails to start for me service avast start

Comment: Yes. I solved it. I am not sure, but I think you need to execute the init script for avast. The init script was in the folder /etc/init.d , I guess. After running this init script, avast creates the scan.sock file etc. So, it worked for me.